# Visual studio puts the exe in a different folder and it wont open

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So for some reason my visual studio now puts the exe and build output in a different folder and the exe wont open. It used to be in Bin/Debug/Project.exe and now it's Bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/project.exe

I managed to open it once and it said something about hostfxr.dll missing, I downloaded that but now it won't open at all.
If it helps, I have .NET 3.1 install, I'm on Windows 10 2004, and Visual Studio 16.6

Comment: Did you change the target platform from .NET Framework to .NET Core?

Comment: oh god yes that was it! I must have missclicked. I'm still kinda new to this. Thanks so much

Comment: @tada66, I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark mark the appropriate reply as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To change the location back to Bin/Debug/Project.exe make the following change in your .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

After that rebuild and verify if all works fine.